# ImportError: No module named PyQt5 : python3

Tags: python, linux

I was trying to learn how to use PyQt5 but at the moment that i want to run my code i got this error

> **ImportError: No module named PyQt5**

I searched about it and i try all the possible solutions but im not able to fix it.
When i run

> pip3 install PyQt5

I get this

> Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.12.3)

And if i run

> python --version

I get

> Python 3.7.5

Now i dont know what to do. I'm using Pop_OS 19.10

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What do you get if you run `which python` and `which pip`?

Comment: Thank you. When i run 'which python' i get '/usr/bin/python' and with 'which pip' i get '/usr/bin/pip' @user35915

Comment: @Emiliano, then ensure that your project interpreter is /usr/bin/python

Comment: I checked and nothing changes, i still get the same error. I'm using vscode @NChechulin

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: I think not @AMC

Comment: @Emiliano It might be something worth considering. I don't know if it will solve this particular problem, but it does dramatically reduce the amount of issues of this kind.

Comment: I'm fairly new with python, so i didn't even consider that. I will see what i can do, thank you @AMC